# What is a difference between instantiate a class?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Everyone,

I'm trying to understand why the exemple 1 return nil ( don't call a goooo function ), and the second exemple call it. Do I need to do something extra ?

Exemple 1 :

```
class A: UICollectionViewCell {

var exempleOneDetail: ExempleOneDetail?

...

}

func handleZoomTap(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   self.exempleOneDetail?.goooo(imageView)

}
```

=>> Result Nil

Exemple 2 :

```
func handleZoomTap(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   let exempleOneDetail = ExempleOneDetail()
   exempleOneDetail?.goooo(imageView)

}
```

=>> Result : Call de function goooo

Thanks for help,
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In example 1, you're never setting `exempleOneDetail` to anything before you call `goooooo()` on it, so it's `nil`.

In example 2, you're creating a *local* variable called `exempleOneDetail` and assigning an initialized object to it, and *then* calling *goooooo()*, so it does what you expect. **However**, be aware that your *local* copy, because it has the *same name* as the instance variable, is *shadowing* that variable, and if you try to use `exempleOneLabel` anywhere outside of `handleZoomTap()`, it will still be `nil` because you never assigned anything to it.

Comment: Perfect, Tks @NRitH , To I use the exemple one, what I need to do ? Tks

Comment: Assign a value to it in some other method that gets called before the tap handler, such as (assuming that this is in a view controller), `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: OK , Thanks for your help